# How to use IF(AND OR) conditions in MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I add those if conditions in my view?

```
@if(Model.Remaining > 0 && Model.Total >= 1)
{
/* do something */
}
@if(Model.Remaining > 0 || Model.Total >= 1 || Model.AmountPaid > 100)
{
/* do something */
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Did you try the above code and it didn't work? What error did it give?

Comment: Er, those are already if conditions in your view...

Comment: for some reason are not working

Comment: You code is correct. You should post more details if you really need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put some kind of HTML control inside your `if` block and make sure the property values defined on the model have values which will cause the code inside the `if` block to render.

**Model:**

```
public class ModelData
{
    public int Remaining { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ModelData { Remaining = 1, Total = 1, AmountPaid = 99 };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MVCTutorial.Models.ModelData

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (Model.Remaining > 0 && Model.Total >= 1)
    {
        <h1>First if...</h1>
    }
    @if (Model.Remaining > 0 || Model.Total >= 1 || Model.AmountPaid > 100)
    {
        <h1>Second if...</h1>
    }
</body>
</html>
```